# Is there an issue with debug mode in 2.4?

Tags: error-message

We've recently updated and now find that in debug mode we sometimes don't get the expected stack trace on error.

With a 500.twig file in place it displays that, otherwise we get the default Internal Server Error summary view.

Is this something that broke in the recent update?

Comment: Per Brad's answer, this is a bug (which has since been fixed). Closing as a "bug report".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in the [current release](http://buildwithcraft.com/updates#build2670) that's been fixed for the next one where PHP Errors/Warnings/Notices won't have the full stack trace shown even if the site is in devMode.

Comment: Can you tell me what the patch is so I can do that now? It's causing a headache with development

Comment: Contact support@buildwithcraft.com.  It involves multiple files.